# Return corresponding value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 2 columns range as the first image shows, and a userform with a 2 column listbox, a textbox and a commandbutton.

[image: image1]

Is there a code so that if I enter a value in the textbox, then the code search my range until it found this value and return the corresponding value from the other column AND ALL THE FOLLOWING VALUES TILL IT COMES TO THE FIRST NON BLANK CELL IN THE FIRST COLUMN.

For example, If I enter "DDD" in the textbox, the first column in the listbox will show "DDD" and the second one will show 444, 555and 666 respectively.

This is the code I'm using, but when I enter "AAA" in the textbox, .end(xldown) goes to "DDD" and not "BBB". Is there a way to solve this ??

Thank u in advance.

```
Dim SearchTerm As String
Dim topCell As Range, BottomCell As Range

SearchTerm = TextBox1.Text

With Sheet1.Range("A:A")
    Set topCell = .Find(SearchTerm, after:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If topCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox SearchTerm & " not found."
    Else
        Set BottomCell = Range(topCell.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Cells(1, 2)

        With ListBox1
            .Clear
            .List = Range(topCell, BottomCell).Value
        End With
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below as a reference to establish which cell is actually the bottom cell for the range of values. Let me know if you need help using it.

```
Sub DoTheThang()
    Dim TopCell As Range
    Dim BottomCell As Range
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim rngUsed As Range

    SearchString = "EEE"

    Set TopCell = Range("A:A").Find(SearchString, Cells(1, 1))
    Set BottomCell = TopCell
    Set rngUsed = Sheet1.UsedRange

    Do While BottomCell.Offset(1).Value = "" And Not Intersect(BottomCell, rngUsed) Is Nothing
        Set BottomCell = BottomCell.Offset(1)
    Loop

    MsgBox TopCell.Address
    MsgBox BottomCell.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Not a problem. To help future users searching for similar answers, please mark the question as answered.

Comment: Is it possible to sort the whole table (if not sorted) by sorting column 1? Taking into consideration that there are blank cells in this column